# How to get path by name ? (meteor iron router)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I want to get a path by name, but I can't find which function I can use.. the iron-router guid is not that clear.. Thank you!!

```
Router.route('/path', {
name: 'newsPage'});

var path = Router.getPath('newsPage');// something like this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That woud be `Router.path("newsPage")`.

You can pass this function 2 additional parameters :

- a context object (key / value dictionary) whose keys will be replaced in the path, ie if your route path is `/user/:username` then if you call `Router.path("userProfile",Meteor.user())`, you will get the path to the currently connected user profile.
- an object to indicate query string parameters and hash value, ie this call `Router.path("newsPage",{},{query:{ts:Date.now()},hash:"about"})` will give you this path : `/path?ts=1433109536938#about`.